# How do you get the node which contains a certain attribute in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example - How to get the node `-L1BchvA8NaQ9Yh7CjS_` which matches email = `tomcruise@firebasemyapp.com`? when the database looks like

```
{
  "-L1BchvA8NaQ9Yh7CjS_" : {
    "createdAt" : 1514187972592,
    "displayName" : "tom cruise",
    "email" : "tomcruise@firebasemyapp.com",
    "firstName" : "tom",
    "lastName" : "cruise",
    "profileLink" : "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png",
    "status" : "happy christmas"
  },
  "-L1CcUEBOECrJJozlHJv" : {
    "createdAt" : 1514204689673,
    "displayName" : "Robert John Downey Jr",
    "email" : "robertjohndowneyjr@firebasemyapp.com",
    "firstName" : "Rober John",
    "lastName" : "Downey Jr",
    "profileLink" : "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png",
    "status" : "happy christmas"
  },
}
```

***Edit:-***

*I am using `react-native.js`.*

Comment: thanks for the edit @rushi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention what language you're using, but I'll answer in javascript and it shouldn't be difficult to change into a different language.

```
var database = firebase.database();
var rootRef = database.ref();

rootRef.orderByChild('email')
        .equalTo('tomcruise@firebasemyapp.com')
        .on('child_added')
        .then(function(snapshot){
            var result = snapshot.val();
            //Do what you want with the result
        });
```

Comment: When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. You need to either use `child_added` or have a loop in your `then()` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i often see `child_added`, `value` and etc.. what are those?

Comment: As said on the documentation, [value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) is used when reading an entire path and [child_added](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) is used when working with lists. I recommend that you read the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) to get a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

*I found solution from [Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs).*

```
var currentUserUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("ARUserProfiles/" + currentUserUID);
dbRef
  .orderByChild("email")
  .equalTo("tomcruise@firebasemyapp.com")
  .once(
    "value",
    response => {
      const val = response.val();
      let responsePayload;
      if (val) {
        responsePayload = Object.entries(val);
        console.log("ARUserProfiles :-", responsePayload);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```